# Getting deprecation reports from Report-To header; Reports are being generated but not being sent

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, content-security-policy

### Unable to get chrome/any browser to send reports generated with Report-To header

Hi, I am trying to collect [Deprecation/Crash/Intervention](https://w3c.github.io/reporting/) reports generated by browsers visiting web pages that trigger an event. I have an endpoint set up that currently receives CSP reports when a browser visits the page, but even though there is a deprecation error in the console and in the log viewer a deprecation report has been generated, it is not being sent by chrome (or safari or firefox).

The `Report-To` header is being delivered, along with the NEL header (which also fails to send reports but is not my focus), as can be seen by scanning my page with securityheaders.com:

[image]

(The max age is short here for a test but I have tried with a full year)

#### Logs

Using `chrome://net-export/` and visiting the page with deprecated JS on it, I can see that in the "Per origin config" section the correct information is being set:

[image: correct per origin config]

and the deprecated JS is generating deprecation reports:

[image: deprecation reports]

but for some reason the reports never send. Sometimes in the log dump it says there have been multiple attempts to send the reports.

#### Tests

I have tried using chrome with the command-line flags `--enable-features=Reporting` and `--enable-blink-features=Reporting` (although I think the three report types are enabled anyway; [Intervention](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5544632075157504), [Deprecation](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5652647952515072) and [Crash](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6683949661159424)). I have also used safari and firefox and received deprecation alerts in the console but the only reports that are sent are CSP reports.

Answer (score 1):

> The Reporting API was designed to be out of band from your web app.
>   The browser captures, queues and batches, then sends reports
>   automatically at the most opportune time. Reports are sent internally
>   by the browser, so there's little to no performance concern (e.g.
>   network contention with your app) when using the Reporting API.
>   There's also no way to control when the browser sends queued reports.

Per the documentation, it doesn't look like this is possible to overcome.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/reportingapi#sending